# Eager loading inside eager loading in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

How to use eager loading inside eager loading? I tried make query like this:
Here is my query in controller:

```
$user_all = User::with('universitas_has_detil')
->whereHas('universitas_has_detil', function ($query) {
    $query->where('jenjang_universitas_id_jenjang', 2)
})->get();
```

And here is my view:

```
@foreach($user->universitas_has_detil as $detil)
{{ $detil->jenjang_universitas->nama_jenjang }},
@endforeach
```

But the result is like this, and not efficient.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer by my self, 
I should using Nested Eager Loading that describes in Laravel documentation